# errors occured after php retrieval in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I finally managed to get json from a php file and use it within my functions. However the consequence of this appears to be that several pieces of functionality that were working perfectly now do not and i have no clue why this is. Another issue which im sure is a key reason why everything is not working is my error in chrome

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'states' of undefined
>   buttonsClick @ index.js:79playClick @ index.js:316window.onload @
>   index.js:320

Here is my code

```
window.onload = function() {

//hangman
  var alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h',
        'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's',
        't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

  var categories;         // Array of topics
  var chosenCategory;     // Selected catagory
  var getHint ;           // Word getHint
  var word ;              // Selected word
  var guess ;             // Guess
  var guesses = [ ];      // Stored guesses
  var lives ;             // Lives
  var counter ;           // Count correct guesses
  var space;              // Number of spaces in word '-'
  var youLost;            //bool to deterime if you have won or lost the game

  // Get elements
  var showLives = document.getElementById("mylives");
  var showClue = document.getElementById("clue");
  var showLivesClick = document.getElementById("mylivesClick")

  //button click test
    //var options = ["cat", "dog", "dragon", "unicorn", "mouse", "horse", "hamster", "giant"];
    var answersblank = ["?", "?", "?", "?","?", "?", "?", "?", "?"];
    var answersid = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida"];
    //var optionstate = ["correct", "correct", "incorrect", "incorrect", "correct", "incorrect", "correct", "incorrect"];
    var counterClick;
    var livesClick;
    var clickQuess;

  // create options ul

  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url;
  var getInfoAll = function(){

      url = "button_click_1.php";
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        console.log("the connection is complete");
        var myJSON = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        buttonsClick(myJSON);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("connection is not made");

    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
  }

var buttonsClick = function (json) {

    myButtonsClick = document.getElementById('buttonsClick');
    myAnswersBlank = document.getElementById('correctAnswers');
    option = document.createElement('ul');
    blankanswer = document.createElement('ul');

      for (var i = 0; i < json.states.length; i++) {

      option.id = 'statesAll';
       listCheck = document.createElement('li');
       listCheck.id = json.states[i].answer;
        console.log(listCheck.id + "  " + json.states[i].answer);
       listCheck.innerHTML = json.states[i].state_name;
       checkClick();
      myButtonsClick.appendChild(option);
      option.appendChild(listCheck);   
       //= json.states[i].image;  
      }

    for (var i = 0; i < answersblank.length; i++) {
        blankanswer.id ='answersblank';
        list = document.createElement('li');
        list.id = answersid[i];
        list.innerHTML = answersblank[i];
        myAnswersBlank.appendChild(blankanswer);
        blankanswer.appendChild(list);
    }
  }


    // Show lives
   commentsClick = function () {
    showLivesClick.innerHTML = "You have " + livesClick + " lives";
    if ((livesClick < 1) && (youLost = false)) {
       reponse = document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "Unlucky! You got " +  counterClick + " correct! Please try again";
      showLivesClick.innerHTML = "Game Over";
      youLost = true;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < answersblank.length; i++) {
      if ((counterClick === answersblank.length) && (youLost == false)){
          if(livesClick >1){
             reponse = document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "Well done! You beat the quiz with " +   livesClick + " lives remaining!";
          }
          else
          {
             reponse = document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = "Well done! You beat the quiz with only " +  livesClick + " life remaining!";
          }
        showLivesClick.innerHTML = "You Win!";
      }
    }
  }


  checkClick = function(){
      listCheck.onclick = function(){
      var choice = this;
      console.log(choice.id);
        if(choice.id == "correct"){
        console.log("it works");
        this.setAttribute("class", "active");
        counterClick +=1;
        selector = choice.innerHTML;
        console.log(selector);
        answer = document.getElementById(selector).innerHTML = choice.innerHTML;
        answer = document.getElementById(selector).style.color = 'green';
        this.onclick = null;
        commentsClick();
        }
        else{
            this.setAttribute("class", "active");
            this.style.color = 'red';
            this.onclick = null;
            livesClick -=1;
            commentsClick();
        }  
      }
  }

  playClick = function(){

      livesClick = 3;
      counterClick = 0;
      youLost = false;
      getInfoAll();
      buttonsClick();
      commentsClick();
  }
  play();
  playClick();

  document.getElementById('resetClick').onclick = function() {
    option.parentNode.removeChild(option);
    playClick();
  }


}
```

the errors seem to occur through commentsClick, buttonsClick

commentsClick - This error is to do with the score - when the user has hit zero they are supposed to be shown the you lose text however the user seems to win with 0 lives remaining which is not the intended functionality

buttonsClick - This error is to do with the undefined states error above...

I have spent days looking over my code and am stumped as to why these errors have occured in result of a the json retrieval. Thanks for any help given

Comment: Please show only the relevant bits of your code, there are hundreds of lines here, 90% of them are irrelevant for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going through the hundreds of lines of your code, seems like you only need to check whether `json.states` exists and only go into this loop if it does:

```
if (json && json.states) {
   for (var i = 0; i < json.states.length; i++) {
   ...
```

---

Explanation:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'states' of undefined buttonsClick @ index.js:79
```

- Problematic function: `buttonsClick`
- In file: `index.js`
- Line number: `79`
- Problematic property: `states`
- The only object you're trying to access that property: `json`
- The problem summary: `json` comes into the function as `undefined`

---

Probably the easiest solution is to store the json that the AJAX returns in a variable and use it from the functions like that, not as an argument.
So this piece of code:

```
    // create options ul

  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url;
  var getInfoAll = function(){

      url = "button_click_1.php";
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        console.log("the connection is complete");
        var myJSON = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        buttonsClick(myJSON);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("connection is not made");

    }
```

needs to become something like:

```
  // create options ul

  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url;
  var json; // we'll keep what AJAX returns in here
  var getInfoAll = function(){

    url = "button_click_1.php";
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        console.log("the connection is complete");
        json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        buttonsClick();
      }
      else
      {
        console.log("connection is not made");

      }
```

And the definition of `buttonsClick` needs to change from:

```
var buttonsClick = function (json) {
    ...
```

to:

```
var buttonsClick = function () {
    ...
```

That way it will read the value of the `json` variable. Make sure the function is never called before the json is ready.

Comment: once i do this i get TypeError: json is undefined - however i do get the json data through... how is this possible? I also do this in another function then pass the data through which is accepted by the function as the parameter json... could this be a reason?

Comment: Ah sorry, I'll update my answer - you should check for `json`, not `json.states`... In your `playClick` function, you're not passing any parameters to `buttonClick`, just this: `buttonsClick();` Is `json` supposed to be a global variable maybe?

Comment: ahhh that has solved the first two issues but the score issues remains.... ehhh yes its suppose to be just the buttonsClick

Comment: It can't be just `buttonsClick` because in that case `json` is undefined... Perhaps you could store the `json` value in a variable after that AJAX call, and then just read it in `buttonsClick`.

Comment: is this not what i am doing.... in any case ur comment has worked for the buttonsClick part. Thanks... however my error with the commentsClick still persists

Comment: No, you were not. In your AJAX callback you were calling buttonsClick with the returned json as a parameter (`buttonsClick(myJSON);`), however, your other function calls `buttonsClick` with no parameters, making its `json` argument `undefined` as I explained first in my answer. I've shown you a way to get around that by using a variable to store and keep the returned json.

Comment: ahhh yes i see what u mean now

Comment: About the comments... it's very hard to read your code, but I see you're checking if lives are less than 0 and also that `youLost` is false. But, I also see you're setting `youLost` to true in the code above. Try removing the `youLost` check in the comments function because it might be already set to true by that other function and thus your comment function fails to recognize the game over.

Comment: perfect that is exactly the problem i believe

Comment: It's probably that, or something very similar. Don't forget: **never do the same functionality in two places - it beats the purpose of functions**.